# How do I permanently store data in a class python

Tags: python, class, store

I have to create a game of Sokoban in Python and I have defined methods in my Sokoban class to find_player() , complete() , get_steps() and move() . I need to create a restart() method and an undo() method but I don't know how to do that. I can't find a way to store the original board or previous boards. I tried making defining another board in the `__init__` but it just updates with `self.__board` instead of saving the initial board. I've also tried making a list in the `__init__` and tried appending each move's "board" to the list but it changes every board in the list. I've attached my code if anyone can help.

```
class Sokoban:
    """Your code here"""
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.__board = board
        self.__original_board = board
        self.__steps = 0
        self.__last_step = []
        self.__position = (0, 0)

    def restart(self):
        first_board = self.__original[0]
        new_board = []
        for i in range(len(first_board)):
             new_board.append(first_board[i])
        print(self.__original)
        return Sokoban(self.__original_board)

    def undo(self):
        return

  

def main(board):
    game = Sokoban(board)
    message = 'Press w/a/s/d to move, r to restart, or u to undo'
    print(message)
    while not game.complete():
        print(game)
        move = input('Move: ').lower()
        while move not in ('w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'r', 'u'):
            print('Invalid move.', message)
            move = input('Move: ').lower()
        if move == 'r':
            game.restart()
        elif move == 'u':
            game.undo()
        else:
            game.move(move)
    print(game)
    print(f'Game won in {game.get_steps()} steps!')


test_board = [
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', 'P', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '#', '*'],
    ['*', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'o', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
]
main(test_board)
```

Comment: Don't use `__` prefixes for variables. It's not quite Pythonic.

Comment: @AKX, could you elaborate on why `__` isn't pythonic? Are you saying [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) use case is not valid?

Comment: Name mangling is for when you're going to mix some names into an existing namespace, and you don't want to accidentally use the same name as something already in that namespace. It's mostly useful for proxy types (that mimic the API of some other class) or for mixin types. Those are both fairly advanced techniques, so don't worry if you don't know about them yet. In any case, you're not doing either of those things here. There's no real need for your variables to be private. You have methods like `get_steps` that could be much more naturally handled by just making `__steps` a public attribute.

Comment: @Chris Yes – as the passage you linked says, the Pythonic convention for private fields is a single underscore. You rarely, if ever, need dunder-cloaked name mangled fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to (deep) copy the board list-of-lists if you don't want the same value (all the way up to `test_board`) to get changed.

```
import copy

# ...

   def __init__(self, board):
        self.__board = copy.deepcopy(board)
        self.__original_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
```

Beyond that, maybe `.restart()` should just reset the game object's state, not return a new object?

```
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.__original_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
        self.restart()

    # ...

    def restart(self):
        self.__steps = 0
        self.__last_step = []
        self.__position = (0, 0)
        self.__board = copy.deepcopy(self.__original_board)
```

That way, a simple `game.restart()` call will do.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without importing anything? I am doing this for an assignment and my lecturer said we were not allowed to import anything.

Comment: Sure, you can implement the 2-dimensional copying yourself (which will be enough in this case): `self.__original_board = [row[:] for row in board]`

Comment: Thank you @AKX I just tried this and it restarts but it only restarts once and then it doesn't again if the user presses "r" a second time in the game, is there any way to fix this or is this something I cannot fix?

Comment: Of course you can fix it. Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing all of the current code you have though.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded my code to github at https://github.com/amistry24/130-Assignment/blob/master/assignment.py so you can see it. Again, thank you so much for having a look at my code. @AKX

Comment: Yeah, the problem is you'll need to again copy the board in the restart: `self.__board = [row[:] for row in self.__original_board]` :)